# How to map a MainValue property using Fluent or LinqToNHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a one to many relationship between my product and image entities. What I'm trying to achieve is to map a main image in the product entity, using Fluent mapping or LinqToNHibernate.

My classes:

```
public class Product {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Image> images { get; set; }
}

public class Image {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsMain { get; set; }
}
```

My mappings:

```
public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product> {
    public ProductMap() {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        HasMany(x => x.images).KeyColumn("id_product");
    }
}

public class ImageClassMap : ClassMap<Image> {
    public ImageClassMap() {
        Table("product_image");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.Product, "id_product");
        Map(x => x.IsMain).Column("is_main");
    }
}
```

I was able to achieve this with QueryOver as follows:

```
Image imageAlias = null;
var product = session.QueryOver<Product>()
    .Where(x => x.Id == 2)
    .Left.JoinQueryOver(x => x.images, () => imageAlias, x => x.IsMain)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Is it possible to have a `MainImage` property in the `Product` class, where IsMain property is true, using Fluent mapping or LinqToNHibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can try,

```
public class Product {
    ...
    public Image MainImage { get; set; }
}
```

and then the mapping,

```
public ProductMap() {
    ...
    HasOne(product => product.MainImage).KeyColumn("main_image_id");
}
```

Comment: What i need is a single image where IsMain == true

Comment: Are you talking about mapping or querying?